Derive relic abandence of Dark Matter
I am reading Dodelson's Modern Cosmology and I have a question about how to derive equation 3.60 from equation 3.59.
Equation 3.59 is
$$\Omega_X = \left[\frac{4\pi^3 G g_*(m)}{45}\right]^{1/2} \frac{x_f T_0^3}{30\langle{\sigma v}\rangle\rho_{cr}}$$
Equation 3.60 is
$$\Omega_X = 0.3h^{-2}\left(\frac{x_f}{10}\right)\left(\frac{g*(m)}{100}\right)^{1/2}\frac{10^{-39}cm^2}{\langle\sigma v\rangle}$$
I find that equation 3.59 should be
$$\Omega_X = \left[\frac{4\pi^3 G g_*(m)}{45}\right]^{1/2} \frac{x_f T_0^3}{30 \langle \sigma v \rangle \rho_{\text{cr}}}c^{5/2}k_b^{-3}\hbar^{3/2}$$
though dimensional analysis.

From what you’ve provided, it isn’t clear how to make $G$, $T_0$, and $\rho_\text{cr}$ disappear and $h$ appear in their place. You’ll need more equations than just those two.

I don’t think your factors of $c$, $k_B$, and $\hbar$ are correct. If I assume that $G$ is the gravitational constant, $T_0$ is a temperature, $\sigma$ is a cross-sectional area, $v$ is a speed, and $\rho$ is an energy density I get $c^{-5/2} k_B^3 \hbar^{-3/2}$. Your exponents are all off by a sign. Whenever you have a temperature, you want a $k_B$ multiplying it to get an energy.

$h^2$ comes from $\rho_\mathrm{cr}$ via the Friedmann equation (using the definition $h\equiv H_0/(100~\text{km/s/Mpc})$). Everything else should just be unit conversions (taking $c=\hbar=k_\mathrm{B}=1$).
